# Image not decoding

Tags: android, bitmapfactory

[image]

I am getting this image as a byte array. So I encode the bytearray and store it in db. Later decode this byte array and saved it in sd card. Issue is that, I am not able to load this image into image view. It tells, skia--> decoder decode false. The bytearray could not be converted to bitmap. Here is the code I used to convert the bytearray to bitmap

**Infact, not even able to open the image in Imagebrowser in android device (I have tried in Es Image browser also). But, this image if I open with chrome browser or HTML viewer, it opens flawlessly.**

```
byte[] byteArray= android.util.Base64.decode(in.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        if (byteArray != null) {
            Log.d(Utilities.class.getSimpleName(), byteArray.toString() + "byteArray Length-->" + byteArray.length);
        } else {
            Log.d(Utilities.class.getSimpleName(), "byteArray is null");
        }
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
```

Encoding code :

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = conn.getInputStream();
            byte[] byteChunk = new byte[4096]; // Or whatever size you want to read in at a time.
            int n;

            while ( (n = is.read(byteChunk)) > 0 ) {
                baos.write(byteChunk, 0, n);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.printf ("Failed while reading bytes from %s: %s", url.toExternalForm(), e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace ();
            // Perform any other exception handling that's appropriate.
        }
        finally {
            if (is != null) { is.close(); }
        }
        response.append(Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Here is the base64 string which I get

[Base64 string of image](http://wikisend.com/download/551544/PHOTO_LOG.txt)

Can anyone help me is sorting out this issue.

Comment: whether  you  encode bytearray as string using base 64 to save it in db

Comment: Yes, I do store it by encoding it with base64

Comment: can u post base64 encoded image string

Comment: @Vishwa, I hava updated my question with the base64 string file.

Comment: i assume that in variable will be base64 string .try byte[] byteArray= android.util.Base64.decode(in, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT); instead of byte[] byteArray= android.util.Base64.decode(in.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);

Comment: @Vishwa, I tried it. Still the same.

Comment: @weston, Added the base64 encoding code

Comment: I don't think it will make any difference, but you should get into habit of calling `.flush()` on writer objects like `ByteArrayOutputStream` before using the written contents (i.e. before `toByteArray()`).

Comment: If you by-pass the base64 for now, does this work? `byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray(); Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);` i.e. is `bitmap` non-null. If so, problem *is* base64, but if it is null, problem is elsewhere (or in both places).

Comment: @weston, I skipped the base64 part as mentioned and the result is still the same. I have got few more updates, when I save the file as somefile.png from the bytearray I receive and I try to use that file as drawable gradle throws error  "crunching cruncher failed for somefile.png" while building. Once if I open the file in mspaint and save it again and now if I use the  file, the error is gone.